# Can you access the VMWare SOAP API using current credentials?

Tags: c#, authentication, vmware

Is there a way to create a `AuthenticationHeader` for the VMWare SOAP API without having to set the `AuthenticationHeader.Password`?  Is there a way of authenticating with Lab Manager using something like a `WindowsIdentity` or `ICredentials` object?

I would like automate this so I am able to deploy machines in a test environment without having to enter a password every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to authenticate to VMware ESX/vCenter using a current credential by [LoginBySSPI](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.SessionManager.html&resultof=%22LoginBySSPI%22%20%22loginbysspi%22%20) method and NTLM or Kerberos security protocol. As far as I know a similar method does not exist in VMWare Lab Manager SOAP API.